# Centos yum crashes and can't install anything

Tags: linux, centos, yum

I have a dedicated server on centos. I want to install a software via a makefile, so I need the "make" package. I've tried to install the "make" package with "yum install make".

During the installing, it freezes for about 30 minutes so I killed the process.

Since then, I cannot install any package. I've tried reinstalling "make" (wich had never finished) and another package.

Yum seems to start but doesn't wirte anything and freezes there.

Is there a way to "restart" yum? Or a way to "repair" it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What `yum install` says? Try to disable all plug-ins by setting `enabled=0` in `/etc/yum.conf` and restart installing.

Comment: it says nothing. I press enter, then nothing happens. Just freeze. I've tried to add enabled=0 in yum.conf. Nothing happens.

Comment: Check the `/var/log/yum.log`. Maybe there you'll find something useful

Comment: I cannot reboot the server now because all my websites will be down for 10-15 minutes.

Comment: In the log file, there is only one line for today: "Apr 11 10:25:30 Installed: 1:make-3.81-19.el6.x86_64". But the installation never finished. Also, every attempts I've made after that didn't log.

Comment: I think, there's no other way, but to reboot. `yum` is not a service - you can't just restart it.

Comment: I've rebooted my server at mdnight and now it's working fine, thank you.